# What does "hit the reputation cap on three different days" mean?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2015

What should I do when I would like to win that hat?

Comment: [What is the daily reputation cap and how can I hit it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32160/what-is-the-daily-reputation-cap-and-how-can-i-hit-it)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to hit 200 reputation or more on 3 days.  *How* that happens [is outlined here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32160/175248).

If you fall short on the upvote count but cross the threshold because of bounties or accepted answers, it will still count.

In other words...you have to submit enough good questions or good answers to the site on three separate days that somewhere between 20-40 different people believe that your contributions are worth an upvote.